# Looping over dataframe to create scatterplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data frame

```
x <- data.frame(id = c("A","B","C"), x_predictor = c(5,6,7), x_depended = c(5.5, 6.5, 7.5), y_predictor=c(2,3,2), y_depended=c(3,3,2), z_predictor=c(12,10,12), z_depended=c(14,11,13))

> x
  id x_predictor x_depended y_predictor y_depended z_predictor z_depended
1  A           5        5.5           2          3          12         14
2  B           6        6.5           3          3          10         11
3  C           7        7.5           2          2          12         13
```

I would like to create a scatterplot for each level on ID and for each pair depended and predictor.

I have created a for loop where I loop over unique levels in ID, but how can I loop over pairs of depended and predictor?

```
uni <- unique(x$id)

for (p in uni){
  print(ggplot(x[x$id==p], aes(y = x_depended,x = x_predictor))+geom_point()
}
```

I would like to plot depended vs predictor. Depended will always be in following column to its predictor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will plot three different scatter plots where each plot will contain the different columns that you have in your data frame.

```
require(ggplot2)
x_plots <- list()
uni <- unique(x$id)
uni_counter <- 0
i <- 0
for (colnum in seq(2, 6, 2)) {
  x_col <- names(x)[colnum]
  y_col <- names(x)[colnum + 1]
  # Retrieve the current uni.
  curr_uni <- uni[uni_counter]
  # Increment our counters
  uni_counter <- uni_counter + 1
  i <- i + 1
  # Create the ggplot command,
  # the command is created dynamically so that we can iterate through
  # different columns in our data frame.
  ggplot_cmd <- paste0("x_plots[[i]] <- ggplot(x[x$id == curr_uni], aes(y = ", y_col, ", x = ", y_col, "))+geom_point()")
  # Evaluate each plot.
  eval(parse(text = ggplot_cmd))
}
```

You can than load the `multiplot()` function posted [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) to draw all the generated plots in one figure using:

```
multiplot(plotlist = x_plots)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I was a away.

Comment: It did help me, but I wanted to loop over both ID and depended with corresponding predictor. 

I couldnt get multiplot function to work.

Comment: I added uni in a bit generic way, you can tune it to your liking. What didn't work with `multiplot`?